# Delete relative path in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, path, relative-path, delete-directory

I'm essentially trying to figure out a simple method for deleting a relative path in vb. I want a user to be able to run the program and delete a specific folder within the AppData/Local folder on Windows. The purpose of the program is to remove Google Chrome user data when the user is finished with their session. I'm running in to trouble with:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory
```

I'm trying to use this method to remove all folders within the \Google folder. The problem is, that since the \Google folder is relative, if anybody besides me tries to use it, it simply wont work since I would use: `My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory("C:\Users\Erik\AppData\Local\Google", FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)`. How can I modify this program to remove the \Google folder under whichever user profile the program happens to be executed under?

Comment: Have a look at the `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialFolders` object and the `Environment.GetFolderPath` method for getting various special folder paths that are relative to the system and the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the Environent Paths:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Directory.Delete(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\Google")
    End Sub
End Class
```

This gets the Local Appdata Path for the current User.